# Android Sliding Menu does not work on tablets; Menu is acting as if in normal handset (slide on button click)

Tags: java, android, menu, slidingmenu, android-sliding

I'm using jfeinstein10 - SlidingMenu. I have already implemented it using a normal handset but when I try my application in a tablet, it still shows the slide button. I followed the tutorial at ResponsiveUI but my menu is still hiding. I want it to be permanently shown when I am using a tablet. Shouldn't be menu_frame.xml automatically be called when using tablets? I tried commenting the part where it ask if menu_frame is null to force it to act in my tablet, but an error shows the menu_frame is not found. I'm confused at how sliding menu really works. Please help! Any idea why is it acting like that in tablet? Here are my source codes:

**BaseActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
getSupportActionBar().hide();
setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

// check if the content frame contains the menu frame
if (findViewById(R.id.menu_frame) == null) {            
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
    getSlidingMenu().setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    getSlidingMenu().setSlidingEnabled(true);
    getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
    getSlidingMenu().setBehindWidthRes(R.dimen.sidebar_default_width);          
} else {
    // add a dummy view
    Log.v("BaseActivity", "menu not null");
    View v = new View(this);
    setBehindContentView(v);
    getSlidingMenu().setSlidingEnabled(false);
    getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);
    getSlidingMenu().setBehindWidthRes(R.dimen.sidebar_no_width);
}

// set the Above View Fragment
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    mContent = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "mContent");
    mMenuPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("menu_position");         
}
if (mContent == null) {
    mContent = new BirdsFragment();
    mMenuPosition = 0;
}   

getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, mContent)
    .commit();

// set the Behind View Fragment
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.menu_frame, new MenuListFragment())
    .commit();

// customize the SlidingMenu
SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
    sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
}
```

**layout/activity_base.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"   
        tools:context=".BaseActivity">

<include layout="@layout/actionbar" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_below="@id/actionbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**layout/menu_frame.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/menu_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the answer. Of course menu_frame can not just be added magically; You have to setup your xml at layout-large and layout-large-land for the menu_frame to appear at a tablet.